# Searching an object in a java map

Tags: java, dictionary, polymorphism, treemap

I am new to Java, I was working with Map class and its derivatives.

I was just wondering about how elements are found inside them. Is only a pointer/reference check performed?

Let's say I have a `TreeMap<MyObject, Integer>`. If I have an object `x` i would like you to search an integer `v` such that its key is "equal" to `x` even if they are 2 separate instances of the class `MyObject`, hence 2 different pointers.

Is there any method (of an interface/superclass too) which can it do such operation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the key is the same, there will only be a single object in the map pointed to by that key.

Comment: all search operations in a map like `containsKey` or `containValue` are based on the `equals` method, so it does not check 'pointer' value but object equality (by default the hashValue)

Answer (score 2):

All the methods that involve comparisons in Map and its implementations make use of the 'equals' method for the objects. If you attempt to add a key+value to a Map which already contains aentry with a key that would compare equals to it, then the new key+value replaces the old one.

See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/):

> For example, the specification for the containsKey(Object key) method says: "returns true if and only if this map contains a mapping for a key k such that (key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))."

The implementation may not execute any equals comparison if it can determine that the keys are 'unequal' through some other means, such as comparing hashcodes.

Comment: Actually I have implemented both methods equals and compareTo, but i ve found as Emmanuel Sys stated before, hashCode method is used for comparison too, but now i need to understand how to use it.

Comment: Comparison consists of the following: 1) Compare hashcodes, if hascodes are not equal then no match. 2) If hashcodes are equal, compare using equals method. There are many questions on stackoverflow discussing the relationship between equals and hashcode, please look at them.

Comment: But are hashcodes used for treemap as well?  As You said in a prev post it used a red black tree, so shouldnt there be hashing, should it?

Comment: Yes, it depends on the underlying Map implementation. TreeMap does not use hashcode (instead, it requires the keys to implement the Comparable interface),  HashMap on the other hand does use hashcode.

Comment: In fact, MyObject class implements Comparable<MyObject> but still no success :(

Comment: I guess there is some more check, cos i ve made a "custom get" method, and even if it passes the equals test, then if i call the get method of the TreeMap class, a null pointer exception is raised.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you would do

```
 TreeMap<MyObject, Integer> tree = ...
 Integer i = tree.get(x);
```

The `get(x)` will iterate over your `keys()` and returning the integer value for the key matching  `aKey.equals(x)`.

Answer (score -2):

In most cases, `Map`s are backed by a hash table, and are very similar to a `HashMap`. `TreeMap` gives a bit more information with each node by having pointers up and down the tree, but lookups are still done via hashes (I believe)

Comment: No. TreeMap uses order over elements (a Comparator or natural order) and does not use hashCodes.

Comment: Treemap in Java is implemented using a red black tree : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree. So there is no hashing.

Comment: @unbeli - Cool. Learn something new every day :)